# .stop(true) doesn't seem to really clear the queue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made this slideshow that pauses when you hover on it with `.stop(true)`. When the mouse leaves the slideshow again it's supposed to play again. It really doesn't matter from where it runs. (meaning it can remove the old animation queue entirely and start over)

The thing is if I hover it now the animation stops, then resumes until it reaches its target. There it stops and wait the time it would take for the animation to finish. I'm not really sure what's going on.

Html:

```
<section class="photo-grid-slideshow">
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>I wanna
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>Dance
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza3.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>With you
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
    </div>
            <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>With you
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza4.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Css:

```
.photo-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100vw / 3);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: left;
}

.photo-grid-slideshow {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 300%;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
  function animate(){
      var p = $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop").css('width');
      $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-of-type").animate({marginLeft: '-=' + p}, 10000, "linear", function(){
        $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
        animate(); // here we call it again
    })
  }
  animate(); // start animation
})

$(".photo-grid-slideshow").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-of-type").stop().clearQueue();
})

$(".photo-grid-slideshow").mouseleave(function() {
    $(function(){
        function animate(){
            var p = $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop").css('width');
            $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-of-type").animate({marginLeft: '-=' + p}, 10000, "linear", function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
            animate(); // here we call it again
        })
    }
        animate(); // start animation
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting a very tricky.
Well your main problem is not has caching the actual margin-left of the first
element, so that is because there is a small time waiting.
first.
the first element are animating, so when the first element is out of the
photo-grid-slideshow this continue animating after you hover in the photo-grid-slideshow, in other words, when you
hover the mouse, the animation stop, but for example, if you stop at -55px
margin-left, and suppose that the width of the image are 200px, then when you
run the animation again, and calculate the width of the first element, that have
255px of width because it takes the last margin-left set and the width of the
element, the reason of that stop some time the animation is for that, the first
element is animating but out of the photo-grid-slideshow, and this is when the second
element is in the start line this stop there and wait for the animation of the first
element finish, because the first element need  255px to finish the animating and this surpass the normal with.

```
    // Get the width of the first element for once, not every time
    var widthEl = parseInt($(".photo-crop").first().css('width'));
    // Need an auxiliar because need cache the margin-left of the first element
    var aux = 0;
    // Separate the function animate it's better
    function animate(p){
        // With this selector you get the first element
        $(".photo-crop").
            first().
            animate({marginLeft: '-=' + p}, 5000, "linear", function(){
                $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
                // You need send the current margin-left
                animate(p); // here we call it again
            });
    };
    // with the chainnable option, you can chain the listeners
    $(".photo-grid-slideshow").mouseenter(function() {
        // Here calculate the margin-left of the first element
        // then you can stop the animation
        aux = widthEl - parseInt($(".photo-crop").first().stop().css("marginLeft"))*-1;
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        // and you can send the current margin-left of the first element.
        animate(aux);
    });
    // here you can send the width of the first element.
    animate(widthEl); // start animation
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for a detailed and clear explanation. Your code works but another problem appeared. Since it's making every animation the same amount of time if it's just 10px left it will still move that distance over 5000ms. However now that I know the problem I might be able to fix that! Thank you again :)